# GA Measurement Protocol does not fire event for just one of the views

Tags: google-analytics, zapier, measurement-protocol

I've setup a Zapier automation to fire an event every time a new deal is made on a 3rd party CRM. The automation triggers fine, and retrieves the GA Client ID stored in the CRM. The goal of this automation is to add the value of the deal to the client's session history. This works completely fine on a new test GA View I made as well as the original one (the one left without any filters).

However, there's one GA View which has both, anti-bot/spider setting and 3 filters set up. I tried disabling all four of them, yet the event still wasn't being fired - not in real-time, nor User Explorer. Wondering what could be the cause of this. All views are, of course, of the same property. Are there any other filters (besides the anti-bot/spider setting and view filters) or options I may have missed that are view-specific that would cause events sent by Zapier not to fire on just this one view?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update of the settings, in the specific case relating to the filters, may not be immediate. If you leave the filters disabled, you can certainly check if after midnight (or after a few hours after midnight) you see that data in the reports.

This happens because after midnight the data is reprocessed again, so for that day (which has therefore become the previous one), if you have removed the filters, you should find all the data.

Comment: Thanks, issue solved by disabling the filter for a longer time.